# 'Add Data' order

Tags: arcgis-desktop

When I 'Add Data' to an ArcMap project, the order of the data which I am choosing from is now in descending (alphabetical) order and I would like to change it back to ascending?  This is not a crucial problem but I have discovered how much I had grown accustomed to ascending order and keep opening the wrong folder / file.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

This is so frustrating, and it took me forever to figure out what caused it. The sort order actually carries over from ArcCatalog. Open ArcCatalog and change the sorting method there by clicking on the Name/Type/Modified/etc. column headers and the setting should carry over to the Add Data dialog windows in ArcMap.

Comment: If this answered your question, please mark it as answered by clicking the check-mark to the left

Answer (score 3):

to add to [the correct answer by @nmpeterson](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/188030/64785) above - you can actually do this from the Add Data dialogue; you don't need to close that dialogue and open ArcCatalog to make this change.

In the Add Data dialogue there is a button Contents View Type which you can click to change the way the dialogue displays data.

[image]

Selecting Details view will give you the column headers you can now click on as per @nmpeterson's answer.

[image]

Once it's re-sorted you can change back to the List default if you prefer it to Details view.

Comment: This is how I'll be doing it from now on, too!